# C, scanning and printing Matrix using Pointers

Tags: c, loops, pointers, matrix, scanf

```
void input(int (*a)[3]){

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        a += i;
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            scanf("%d",*a+j);

    }
}

void print_matrix(int (*a)[3]){

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        a += i;
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%d ",*(*a+j));
        printf("\n");
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

int main(){

    int matrix[3][3];
    input(matrix);

    printf("Printing matrix using function: \n");
    print_matrix(matrix);


    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter matrix like this:

> 1 1 1
>
> 2 2 2
>
> 3 3 3

Printing matrix using function produces correct output: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3.

But printing matrix using two loops produces output like this:

> 1 1 1
>
> 2 2 2
>
> -5555 0 -22222

So I obviously have some error, but I can't figure out where. What I don't understand here is why this won't work for third row in matrix.

**Note:** I know this can be done without using pointers and functions, but that is not the point here, I want to do it exactly like this, just can't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `a += i;` with `a += 1;` in both the functions `void input(int (*a)[3])` and `void print_matrix(int (*a)[3])`.

The reason is when i is 2 it goes out of the boundary. You are adding 2.

Also, move `a += 1` after the 2nd for loop.

Comment: replace `a += i;` with `a += 1;` is wrong. because first time should just `a`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you're manipulating `a` in both `input` and `print_matrix`.

In `input`:

```
    a += i;     // problem is here
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        scanf("%d",*a+j);
```

On the first iteration, `a` is fine since 0 is added.  It's also fine on the second, as 1 is added to move it to the next row.  But on the third, it is incremented by 2, moving it outside of the bounds of the matrix.

You could simply replace `a += i` with `a++`, but if you do then you'll be writing everything one row down from where it should be.

Sample output with `a += i` replaced with `a++`:

```
[dbush] /tmp/x1
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
Printing matrix using function:
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

0 0 -668873792
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

For this to work properly, move `a++` to the bottom of the outer `for` loop.

In `input`:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        scanf("%d",*a+j);
    a++;
}
```

In `print_matrix`:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        printf("%d ",*(*a+j));
    printf("\n");
    a++;
}
```